# Tag merge request: [expressions] tag into [phrases] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Previously, [expression-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-requests) tag was merged into [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) tag.
Pertaining Meta post: [What are [expression-requests] tag for?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/)

In that respect, the [expressions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions) tag should be merged into the [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) tag also.

Additional small request: It would make sense to rename the [expression-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression-choice) tag to [phrase-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-choice) for consistency.

<sub>Note: I've tried to add [expressions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions) tag as a synonym to [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) tag but it doesn't work like that.

https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrases/synonyms

Error message:</sub>

> <sub>Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Reverse synonym expressions already proposed on the tag expression</sub>

Comment: How does one do this merge? How does one vote for your suggestion (I'm all for it)? How does one interact with the tagging system at all? Yes, I've been here a while and interacted with the tag system. The most charitable way to say what I think of it is that I have a lot of difficulty using it... I'm having a long learning curve with it. Anyway this -should- be easy to do where 'should' = 'is desirable to', not 'I expect this to'.

Comment: @Mitch Mods can synonymize/merge/rename any tag with a few clicks. The tools given to non-mods to do so are so useless that your best bet is always to bring it here to meta so that a mod can make the changes you want (assuming there's a consensus).

Comment: @Laurel Those moderator tools like easier content editing of tags should be accorded to non-mods with sufficient rep, since they are appropriate to those with sufficient experience here (unlike managing disputes or sockpuppets.) But that's a system-wide request/situation isn't it?

Comment: @Mitch I agree, and it's something I find frustrating on other sites too. You should check out [Can we allow 7.5K users to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in the tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103211/323179)

Comment: @Laurel Re: the MSE status declined link. I wish that question was revisited by the staff now. The community consensus is apparently clear about it. We need high rep users to be able to do it rather than have it on meta.

Comment: +1. I just came upon [expression-choice], which doesn't necessarily involve expressions: [phrase-choice] would fit the bill a lot better. Can this be reconsidered? We have more mods here :)